What is the purpose of specifying an <activity-alias> with "android:enabled" as false?
I'm looking at an application that describes several  elements in the Android Manifest but with "android:enabled" as false. The docs state the attribute specifies

Whether the target activity can be instantiated by the system through this alias. "true" if it can be, and "false"

What would be the purpose of specifying an activity-alias if not to be able to instantiate it or call it directly with the android:name attribute?

<activity-alias> is element in the Android Manifest that allows you to create an alternative name for an existing activity. This is useful when you want the same activity to be launched in different ways or with different settings.
Suppose you have an activity called ConfigActivity, and you want it to be able to be launched as the main activity of the app, as well as a separate activity for specific tasks.
<application
...>

<!-- Target Activity -->
 <activity
        android:name=".ConfigActivity"
        android:label="Config Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Alias for Configuration A -->
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".ConfigAliasA"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:targetActivity=".ConfigActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.CONFIG_A" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>

    <!-- Alias for Configuration B -->
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".ConfigAliasB"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:targetActivity=".ConfigActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.CONFIG_B" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>

</application>

This setup allows ConfigActivity to be launched with different configurations based on the intent action received, providing flexibility in how the activity is used within the application.

You can enable or disable specific activities based on conditions such as user preferences, app configuration, or feature flags (Example above ⬆️ )
Sometimes developers include stubs for future features. The alias can be disabled initially and enabled in a future update without requiring significant changes to the manifest file
During development, you can temporarily disable specific components without removing them from the manifest and then re-enable.
In some cases, certain features or activities may only be relevant to certain regions. You can disables the alias for regions where features doesn't apply


Your example specifies "android:enabled" as true which explains all the use-cases you mentioned. What would be the purpose of specifying an alias with "android:enabled" as false?

@user27462308 for example for use-case 2 you can specify "android:enabled" = false. but even for all use-cases you can specify "android:enabled" = false. It will simply not be used then, but if needed, you can turn it on again. If you don't need to test your program with different inputs - you can remove it

another example, you can create different builds of your application and specify when some functionality is available ("android:enabled" = true) and unavailable ("android:enabled" = false)
